# Create a picklable Python class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class, debugging

I am trying to create some custom Python classes for my application. When I try to debug my code I can not pick the instances of my custom classes, I receive the error "Object XXX is not picklable".
I found this page https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled but I don't understand how I should implement the methods that make my class picklable.
For example how would you modify the following classes so that I can pick instances of them?

```
class Point3D:
  def __init__ (self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

  def move(self, vector):
    self.x += vector.x
    self.y += vector.y
    self.z += vector.z
    return

  def isValidPoint(self):
    isNotValid = False
    isNotValid = math.isnan(self.x) or math.isnan(self.y) or math.isnan(self.z)
    return not isNotValid
```

And

```
class PointCloud3D:
  def __init__ (self):
    self.points = []    

  def getNumberOfPoints(self):
    return len(self.points)

  def addPoint(self, point):
    self.points.append(point)
    return

  def addPointCloud3D(self, additionalPointCloud3D):
    for self.point in additionalPointCloud3D:
        self.addPoint(point)

  def getCloudCenter(self):
    numberOfPoints = self.getNumberOfPoints()
    centersSumX = 0
    centersSumY = 0
    centersSumZ = 0
    for point in self.points:
        centersSumX = centersSumX + point.x
        centersSumY = centersSumY + point.y
        centersSumZ = centersSumZ + point.z
    centerX = centersSumX/numberOfPoints
    centerY = centersSumY/numberOfPoints
    centerZ = centersSumZ/numberOfPoints

    center = Point3D(float(centerX), float(centerY) , float(centerZ))

    return center
```

While here you can find the code that I am trying to debug:

```
from classDatabase import Point3D, PointCloud3D

testPoint1 = Point3D(1.5, 0.2, 2.3)
testPoint2 = Point3D(3.5, 1.2, 5.3)

testPointCloud3D = PointCloud3D()
testPointCloud3D.addPoint(testPoint1)
testPointCloud3D.addPoint(testPoint2)
```

Finally a screenshot of the issue:
[image]

Comment: fix indentation

Comment: "Picklable", not "pickable".

Comment: Instances of these classes are pickable. Show your code which is getting error

Comment: Added the code and a snapshot. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I can do `pickle.dumps(textPointCloud3D)` in Python 3.5.2. Are you sure nothing else is going on?

Comment: @9000 Sorry but can you give me some hints on what I should check? On my computer is not working.

Comment: @user3555654: What I'd do: comment out as many data fields in `Point3D` and `PointCloud`, up to having no fields initialized in constructors, even though some methods won't work, and try to pickle them. With mostly empty classes, the pickling should wirk. Add the fields back and see if it's still picklable. If not, you'll see which filed exactly leads to a problem. If you can't understand and fix the problem readily, update this question :)

Comment: I tried the code on the first online interpreter available and it runs correctly. Are you sure there are no other parts of code? I'm wondering if, for any reason, Point3D exists in another library you're importing and is aliasing your custom class.